# Parse multiple JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I'm able to parse a single object using JSON.parse.

```
var testing = '{"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "2883267603"}';
var itemsObject = JSON.parse(testing);
```

But when I try to parse a variable with multiple objects:

```
var testing = '{"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "2883267603"}, {"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "3084880561"}'; 
var itemsObject = JSON.parse(testing);
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

Comment: you try to parse an Array, try put [ and ] at the begining and the closing of the string

Answer (score 4):

You need to make an array of objects

```
var testing = '[{"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "2883267603"}, {"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "3084880561"}]';
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `testing` is now an array of (as you say - multiple) objects, and you should add square brackets around them to indicate that:

```
var testing = '[{"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "2883267603"}, {"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "3084880561"}]';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :
var testing = '[{"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "2883267603"}, {"appid": "730", "contextid": "2", "amount": "1", "assetid": "3084880561"}]'; 
var itemsObject = JSON.parse(testing);